# Django on GAE: Resource could not be found

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I have a Django app that renders some web pages to let people submit some information to my database. The project structure is like:

```
--wun/
  --manage.py
  --templates/uploader/
     --some_html_files.html
  --static/uploader/
     --css_files.css
  --wun/
    --settings.py
    --urls.py
    --wsgi.py
  --uploader/
    --app_files.py
```

So the project is called `'wun'` and my app is called `'uploader'`. The structure is typical Django.

There's no issue running it on Django's development server locally, but when deployed it to GAE, I get `404 Not Found` on every url endpoint I visit. I turned the `DBUG` on in Django settings but there's not other information. I can see the endpoints been visited on GAE's log.

I think maybe GAE cannot find the static files and templates? I have the following settings in Django:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR,os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

On App Engine:

```
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /static/uploader
   static_dir: /static/uploader
- url: .*
  script: wun.wsgi.application
```

But I don't think the first two urls are used here, since I don't serve pages directly. All pages are rendered by Django views from templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that GoogleAppEngineLauncher automatically created another folder under my project folder, and it is using the app settings there which has nothing. So when the server was visited, there was actually no Django app running, it is just an empty server.